# Running a Linux executable via Process.Start gives: Exec format error

Tags: c#, .net, linux, cross-platform

I have a small C#/.NET6.0 commandline application that should run a certain linux command via `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Compressonator/compressonatorcli_linux_x86_64_4.2.5150/compressonatorcli"),
    ArgumentList = { "-fd", compression, "-noprogress", fileName, outputFilename },
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
process.WaitForExit();
```

However this fails with the following exception on an Ubuntu 64bit running in a VirtualMachine:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): An error occurred trying to start process '/media/sf_imageconverter/net6.0/Compressonator/compressonatorcli_linux_x86_64_4.2.5150/compressonatorcli' with working directory '/media/sf_imageconverter/net6.0'. Exec format error 
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

The strange thing is, that when running the process directly from a terminal on the same machine it works fine:

```
$/media/sf_imageconverter/net6.0/Compressonator/compressonatorcli_linux_x86_64_4.2.5150/compressonatorcli
```

The process is https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/compressonator/releases/tag/V4.2.5185

My .NET6.0 app is set to compile to `AnyCPU` but I have also tried the other options without success.

Comment: what happens when you set UseShellExecute = true ?

Comment: @DaiBok This seems to work, but then I can not capture the Standard Output and Standard Error streams, which are important my case.

Comment: This seems to be a good comprehention: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/10/29/the-net-process-class-on-linux#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you are not launching an executable but a script. If you open the script in a text editor, you can see that the second line contains this code

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This is called a shebang and specifies what executable is used to run this script. If your system does not have `/bin/bash` you will get this error message.

Either make sure that bash is available or change the line to the shell you are using to execute the script directly.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue. I did not realize that it was a script because it didnt have a .sh or similar file extension.